# problem with prepare the device for development

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have Xcode 14.01 with macos 12.5 and and iOS 16.6.1 on iPhoneSE 2021.
I am not able to load an app I designed long ago. Loading to my previous iPhone6 works well switching to iOS 15.0.

I get the message

> Failed to prepare the device for development.

I tried nearly every advice on this forum, like updating software, loading device support version 16.1, unpairing, restarting every device, always trusting the macbook with no success.
I also tried with a blank test app with the same result.

Any other posibilities?

Update:

I got the occasion to run the code on a machine with macos 13.6 ventura and Xcode 14.3. The upload of the app to my iphone run without problems.Back on my own machine, uploading also run without problems without changing anything.